# Cannot find Package fop ( Ithink)

Tags: java, apache-fop

Hello friends I try to use fop engine programatically I search for an example and I find this class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXResult;

import org.apache.avalon.framework.ExceptionUtil;
import org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.ConsoleLogger;
import org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Logger;

import org.apache.fop.apps.Driver;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException;
import org.apache.fop.messaging.MessageHandler;

public class Invokefop 
{

    public void convertXML2PDF(File xml, File xslt, File pdf) 
                throws IOException, FOPException, TransformerException {
        Driver driver = new Driver();
        Logger logger = new ConsoleLogger(ConsoleLogger.LEVEL_INFO);
        driver.setLogger(logger);
        MessageHandler.setScreenLogger(logger);       
        driver.setRenderer(Driver.RENDER_PDF);
        OutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(pdf);
        try {
            driver.setOutputStream(out);
            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslt));
            Source src = new StreamSource(xml);
            Result res = new SAXResult(driver.getContentHandler());
            transformer.transform(src, res);
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("JAVA XML2PDF:: FOP ExampleXML2PDF\n");
            System.out.println("JAVA XML2PDF:: Preparing...");

            File base = new File("../");
            File baseDir = new File(base, "in");
            File outDir = new File(base, "out");
            outDir.mkdirs();


            File xmlfile = new File(baseDir, args[0]);
            File xsltfile = new File(baseDir, args[1]);
            File pdffile = new File(outDir, args[2]);

            System.out.println("JAVA XML2PDF:: Input: XML (" + xmlfile + ")");
            System.out.println("JAVA XML2PDF:: Stylesheet: " + xsltfile);
            System.out.println("JAVA XML2PDF:: Output: PDF (" + pdffile + ")");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("JAVA XML2PDF:: Transforming...");

            Invokefop app = new Invokefop();
            app.convertXML2PDF(xmlfile, xsltfile, pdffile);

            System.out.println("JAVA XML2PDF:: Success!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(ExceptionUtil.printStackTrace(e));
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

All the Libs from Fop are in the Classpath including the fop.jar in build directory. After
I run the`javac Invokefop.java` I get this error:

```
> C:\....\fop>javac Invokefop.java
Invokefop.java:21: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Driver
location: package org.apache.fop.apps
import org.apache.fop.apps.Driver;
                          ^
Invokefop.java:23: package org.apache.fop.messaging does not exist
import org.apache.fop.messaging.MessageHandler;
                               ^
Invokefop.java:31: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Driver
location: class Invokefop
        Driver driver = new Driver();
        ^
Invokefop.java:31: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Driver
location: class Invokefop
        Driver driver = new Driver();
                            ^
Invokefop.java:36: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable MessageHandler
location: class Invokefop
        MessageHandler.setScreenLogger(logger);
        ^
Invokefop.java:39: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Driver
location: class Invokefop
        driver.setRenderer(Driver.RENDER_PDF);
                           ^
6 errors
```

I am relatively new to Java, but with this approach I try to execute the fop engine in c++ using this  java class..

Have anybody some Idea, how to solve this errors...
Thanx in advance..

Answer (score 1):

The classes that are coming up with "cannot find symbol" errors don't exist in the `fop.jar` file.

I just downloaded v0.95 of the FOP library, and I can't see those classes in any of the jar files in the distribution. (You can open a jar file in any zip program and have a look - a jar is basically a zip file with a few extra bits in there that Java uses).

I would guess that the classes referenced in your example code were removed at some stage from the FOP library, and the example is for the older version. So you could try and find an older version of the library that contains those classes, or look for newer examples. The binary distribution comes with some examples - maybe have a look through those to see if any are useful for you?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added the dependency in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```